# Best practice in react when come to className style Technique

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm new in `react.Js` and Usually I'm doing my styling in `vue.js` or `vanilla (pure HTML, CSS, JS)`. I have some question regarding ClassName Best Practice in `React`. I want to ask regarding best practice when giving a className in ReactJs (It will be helpful if you give me reason such as advantage and disadvantage when using one of the style).

Let we said that I have a Page in `React.Js` with some css file in `scoped` and `global`. Here there is some technique I use when do styling in `React.Js` or Stating my class in there:

1. `className={styles.scopedCSS}` --> I'm using scoped styling in this example `import styles from './mycode.css'`
2. `className="Global-CSS"` --> I'm using global css file let say `app.css`

in general there is this two technique, but what Poke my curiosity is when you using a more complex and Custom CSS style in your project such as combining `global` and `scoped` CSS. this is the current technique I find:

1. `` className={`Global-CSS Global-CSS ${styles.ScopedCSS} ${styles.ScopedCSS}`} ``
2. `` className={`Global-CSS Global-CSS ${styles.['scoped-css', 'scoped-css']}`} ``
3. `className={Style.constStylingName}` --> for this I'm using `` Const constStylingName = `Global-CSS Global-CSS ${styles['scoped-css', 'scoped-css']} `` to write my full CSS lines so I'm only using one lines to defined my `ClassName` in here you can use `terniary operation` too if you want to add some logic in here.
4. `style={marginLeft: 0, display: 'flex', etc.}` --> Straight up using `full Styles inline` in my code

for information I'm really curious about this, since I find it quite an interesting topic that not a lot of article I find it useful for me to explain the differences and I had quite a discussion as one of the technique above only will make your code looks like a spaghetti code when your project becoming more larger in scale.

I hope someone can help me to explain this problem to me since I'm really want to learn about this styling technique issue in react.

Comment: you can check the `BEM` methodology. This method is not just for `react`, it's for cases when you have a big project and want to have not repeating class names.
https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/

Comment: @Hovakimyan Thankyou for your comment and `BEM reference` article. it is new for me to learn the name of the concept itself, usually I'm using this concept when I divide and conquer my class into a very specific class. but it seems it match with the normal class in `general section point 2`. But thankyou for the new information, since I'm using this method but doesn't know the name of the concept itself

Answer (score 0):

To implement className dynamically, I suggest a npm package `classnames` https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames.

For example, you can use it like this (very convenient for conditional classes):

```
import cn from classnames;

className={cn('text-bold', 'font-xl')}
className={cn('text-bold', {'font-xl': userInput === 'xl'})}
```

If you're using scoped css, better check out css module instead of normal css. Emotion and styled-components are some alternatives if you're interested in css-in-js, which is quite popular for React styling.